# How do I "shift" Caps Lock, Shift and Control?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xmodmap, remapping

Default key location is

```
+-----------+
| Caps Lock |
+-----------+
| L Shift   |
+-----------+
| L Control |
+-----------+
```

I'd like to try moving the most usually useless key to the farthest position, but at the same retain the notion that `Control` is below `Shift`:

```
+-----------+
| L Shift   |
+-----------+
| L Control |
+-----------+
| Caps Lock |
+-----------+
```

Is this possible?

Currently using 16.04, but planning to upgrade to 18.04 in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file `~/.Xmodmap` with the following contents:

```
remove Shift = Shift_L
remove Control = Control_L
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode 50 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 37 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
add Shift = Shift_L
add Control = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

That should leave it ready for the next login. Apply immediately by running

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Thanks to @Andra for this solution.